# Does dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: retain previous view controllers?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I am having memory leaks and crashes in my app and I would like to know if they could be due to the way my container View Controller switches between View Controllers. The app should allow the user to navigate a long series of pages. Each page is laid out as a ViewController in the Storyboard (each page has a number as its identifier).

By the time I get to page 14 in the app, I can see in Instruments' Activity Monitor that the  app takes about 600MB of memory (on an iPad 3). This is because each view controllers have UIImageViews with big images.

**I am using ARC.**

Below is the code for the container View Controller. Can you see a memory management problem somewhere?

```
@implementation PageNavigator

int startingPage = 0;
int currentPage = 0;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"Starting book from page %d", startingPage);

    //do this only the first time the app runs
    if(startingPage != -1){
        UIViewController *currentPageVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startingPage]];
        [self presentModalViewController:currentPageVC animated:YES];
        currentPage = startingPage;
        startingPage = -1;
    }
}

//currentPageVC and its outlets should get released when it gets out of scope, right? 
-(IBAction)goToNextPage{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        currentPage++;
        UIViewController *currentPageVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentPage ]];
        [self presentModalViewController:currentPageVC animated:YES];

        NSLog(@"Current Page is %d", currentPage); 
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When `dismissViewControllerAnimated` is called control goes to dealloc method of that controller, if you are not using ARC and allocating memory to some UI Controls then you need to release those, and also with this you won't need to take care of view controller's memory.

Comment: As I mention in the question, I am using ARC.

Comment: @Eric - sorry that is mentioned in last so i missed.Anywat you can check that at the time of dismissViewControllerAnimated , dealloc method is called so if you done some manual memory handling, you can handle there.